# ProcessBuilder SFTP Java Linux

Tags: java, linux, processbuilder

I am trying to send a csv file by calling a sh file. But it does not detect the sh file in the path of the linux machine. For now I just want to get to that file. Then I would have to pass parameters to treat them in the sh and do SFTP of the csv to another machine.

Java code.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
pb.command("/home/openiam/scriptsftp.sh");
Process process = pb.start();
```

Sh path.

[image]

Sh code.

[image]

Linux output

```
[addCSVFile]  Error to add/create csv operation file: Cannot run program "/home/openiam/scriptsftp.sh": error=2, No such file or directory
```

Comment: Personally I would invoke the shell interpreter explicitly. The first element in your array or ```List``` should probably be ```/bin/bash``` followed by the (correct and full) path to the script. And then of course, the next *five* arguments are the parameters to the script you posted. Make sure you handle stderr properly

Comment: Oh and you can eliminate one other potential weakness by using the full path to ```lftp```

Comment: Is it correct to assume that shell script has execute bits set?

Comment: @HiranChaudhuri. Probably not ;) But even if they were and it executed, the process would fail because no parameters were passed

Comment: Yes, it would fail. But that is to solve once the script fails. Currently it is not even invoked.

Comment: @g00se the error still appears in the console. I have tried putting /bin/sh /home/openiam/scriptsftp.sh or /bin/bash /home/openiam/scriptsftp.sh and it keeps returning No such file or directory

Comment: Can we have output of following please?
```ls -l /home/openiam/scriptsftp.sh```

Comment: @g00se -rwxrwxrwx. 1 openiam openiam 76 Oct  5 09:41 /home/openiam/scriptsftp.sh

Comment: I don't understand where that error output is coming from. Can you please inherit stderr and post up the full code you're running and *how* it's being run